# не знаю как получить токен для сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, requests

хочу спарсить [сайт](https://www.perekrestok.ru/) Нашёл у них [api](https://www.perekrestok.ru/api/customer/1.4.1.0/catalog/), но не понимаю как получить ключ для доступа(выдаёт ошибку`{"content":null,"error":{"code":"ACCESS_TOKEN_INVALID","message":"Access token invalid."}}`) Помогите пожалуйста написать код, что бы можно было получить инфу из этой api...
Сам сайт отдаёт куки, но я не могу понять как их привинтить к запросу, который я кидаю в api(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот сайт выдает ключ доступа, при первом заходе на него, и хранит у себя. Чтоб его получить достаточно открыть инструменты разработчика, перейти в раздел сеть. Дальше перезагружайте страницу, и увидете как пойдут все запросы, которые делает сайт. При клике на запрос, будет показана вся информация о нем. И вот здесь то, что нам нужно. В одном из запросов будет указан этот ключ, в качестве заголовка что-то вроде:

```py
"Auth" : "Bearer oeqwrpppa909vbd99srpasdfp023240230s0dfsdf...."
```

Все это копируйте и добавляйте к каждому запросу, в качестве заголовка вот так:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "Auth" : "Bearer oeqwrpppa909vbd99srpasdfp023240230s0dfsdf...",
}

r = requests.get(
        url="https://www.perekrestok.ru/api/customer/1.4.1.0/catalog",
        headers=headers,
    )

# Выведем всю информацию полученную в json
print(r.json())
```